# Get the first unique element from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I was solving the problem on LeetCode. i.e [Single Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number/).

You need to create a function which takes a array as input and return the only element which is not repeated in array. The array will contain only one element like that.

```
[2,2,1] //1
[2,3,5,2,3] //5
```

I have solved the problem with the code below.

```
var singleNumber = function(nums) {
    let obj = {}  
    for(let a of nums){
        obj[a] = obj[a] + 1 || 1;
    }
    for(let key in obj){
        if(obj[key] === 1) return key;
    }
};
```

However after submitting the result it says

> Runtime: 68 ms, faster than **72.96%** of JavaScript online submissions for Single Number.

I am curious to know what is more efficient method for this problem.

Comment: I think LeetCode's speed indicator is not sufficiently trustworthy. Try Submitting multiple times - I saw quite a difference, even with the same code, eg faster than 73% vs faster than 35%. I tried using a Set instead, but it had the same speed as yours

Comment: @CertainPerformance How you used `Set` for that. Can you give code so I may check.

Comment: It was just a random idea that didn't pan out (I didn't think it would anyway), but: `var singleNumber = function(nums) {
    const numSet = new Set();
    for (const num of nums) {
        if (numSet.has(num)) {
            numSet.delete(num)
        } else {
            numSet.add(num);
        }
    }
    return numSet.values().next().value;
};` Idea was to avoid the numeric counting

Comment: @CertainPerformance It seems that you are right _"LeetCode's speed indicator is not sufficiently trustworthy"_. But I got the best solution for that. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical solution for non-repeating single number (where numbers are integers and repeated ones are repeated exactly once) is just computing the x-or of all of them:

```
var singleNumber = function(nums) {
    let res = 0;
    for(let x of nums) res ^= x; // shorthand for res = res ^ x
    return res;
};
```

Note that if an explicit index-based `for` loop or a `for-of` or `.forEach` is faster or slower depends on the specific Javascript engine. For example:

```
var singleNumber = function(nums) {
    let res = 0;
    for(let i=0,n=nums.length; i<n; i++) res ^= nums[i];
    return res;
};
```

*may* be faster than the `for ... of` approach.

Comment: It definitely *looks* like it should be faster, but when I submitted it, it said `Runtime: 76 ms, faster than 51.11% of JavaScript online submissions for Single Number.` (tried again, got 64ms / 81%) (see comment on question, I doubt their speed indicator is trustworthy)

Comment: Depending on the Javascript engine `for(let x of y)` or `forEach` can be slower than an explicit indexed loop

Comment: @6502 Can you please explain what `res ^= x;` does?

Comment: @MaheerAli: `res ^= x` is a shorthand for `res = res ^ x` and `^` is the bit-a-bit x-or operation on integers.

Comment: @MaheerAli `3 ^ 3` is 0, and `3 ^ 0` is 3, so the numbers that show up even number of times cancel each other. It would not work in most cases if the repeating numbers show up odd number of times which is why the description has "every element appears twice except for one"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `XOR` logic to check unique number, since in the problem description it is mentioned each element occurs twice except one.
`A XOR A` is 0. This property is helpful in determining the unique number.

```
var singleNumber = function(nums) {
    return nums.reduce((prev, curr) => prev ^ curr, 0)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do it:

```js
function getUniqueEl(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let temp = arr.lastIndexOf(arr[i]);
    if (temp !== i) {
      delete arr[temp];
    } else {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
}
     
console.log(getUniqueEl([2, 2, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested speed, but I like this solution to finding a unique element.

```
function findUniq(arr) {
  return arr.find(n => arr.indexOf(n) === arr.lastIndexOf(n));
}
```